# Django redirection after login

Tags: django, authentication

I have an app where I'm trying to allow login by username alone. I've been doing this:

```
@login_required(login_url='/login')
def index(request):
    # bunch of queries to provide to the add_rule.html via context
    return render(request, "index.html", context=context)


def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'registration/login.html')
    else:
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        user = authenticate(username=username) # custom function 
        login(request, user)

        # somehow return the above previous index() function with the request that has updated login/username information
```

I'm not exactly sure how I can render the index.html template with the request that now has the login information. The docs are not clear on how things get redirected after login. I apologize if there is not enough information.

Answer (score 0):

The [**`login_required`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) has a `redirect_field_name` parameter. This specifies the name of the GET parameter that will encode the path from which the redirection was made. By default, that parameter is `'next'`.

You can thus redirect with:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'registration/login.html')
    else:
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        user = authenticate(username=username) # custom function 
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.GET.get('next', ''))
```

You will however have to implement some extra logic in case the authentication fails, etc.

The [**`LoginView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView) has a slightly more complex [implementation [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L127) that aims to fetch this from the `POST` parameters, `GET` parameters, and does some validation to check if the path is safe.